# PreparedStatement nsert logical operation (=,<,>=,<,>=) in my sql

Tags: java, sql

I want to insert logical operations (=,<,>=,<,>=) in my sql

```
try {
        String sql = "SELECT id,name,date_N FROM LECTEUR  WHERE date_N ?,?";

        Connection con = DBinfo.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, operationCB.getValue());
        ps.setString(2, date1.toString());
        ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

output:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
```

Comment: You can't insert an operator using a statement parameter. You'd have to insert it into the string itself.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only insert values as parameters of the `PreparedStatement`.
If you want the operation to be dynamic, use a `StringBuilder` to build the query `String`:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("SELECT id,name,date_N FROM LECTEUR ");
sql.append("WHERE date_N ");
sql.append(operationCB.getValue());
sql.append(" ?");
Connection con = DBinfo.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
ps.setString(1, date1.toString());
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a logical operator to a prepared statement using a `?` placeholder.  One workaround would be to maintain separate queries for the various logical operations:

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
queryMap.put("=", "SELECT id, name, date_N FROM LECTEUR WHERE date_N = ?");
queryMap.put(">", "SELECT id, name, date_N FROM LECTEUR WHERE date_N > ?");
// etc.

try {
    String sql = queryMap.get(operationCB.getValue());  // fetch the appropriate statement
    Connection con = DBinfo.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setDate(1, date1);
    ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```